# Ability to resume/reject a TFS release after a manual intervention

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In TFS 2017 Update 1 (On-Prem) there is a release definition with a manual intervention step in between. The manual intervention notification is set for a group where an user User1 is not part of. User1 has Builder and Project Admin rights; And is also part of the TFS team.

During the manual intervention of a release User1 is able to resume or reject the release. But we don't want this to happen.

I could not find the rights in TFS Microsoft online documentation for being able to do this.

What rights are needed to resume or reject a release after a manual intervention step?

P.S. In TFS 2018 RC2 too I noticed the same scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the Manual Intervention task is activated during a deployment, it
>   sets the deployment state to **IN PROGRESS** and displays a message
>   bar containing a link that opens the Manual Intervention dialog
>   containing the instructions. After carrying out the manual steps, the
>   administrator or user can choose to resume the deployment, or reject
>   it.
>
> Users with **Manage deployment** permission on the environment can
>   *resume* or *reject* the manual intervention.

If you don't want the *User1* be able to resume or reject the release. You could deny the Manage deployment permission for that specific user. More detail info about it please refer: [The Manual Intervention task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/phases#agentless-phase)