# Manual intervention is not available in TFS-2018

Tags: tfs, devops, release-management

I'm trying to find the manual intervention task in the release management of my on Prem- TFS

As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603949/ability-to-resume-reject-a-tfs-release-after-a-manual-intervention?rq=1) this is available in TFS 2017. By May it's removed in the latest release?

I searched through the TFS marketplace, but no luck so far.

`My TFS Configuration is` **16.122.27319.1 (Tfs2018.Update1.RC1)**

Could somebody help me to get this task in my release definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 types of phases or ("jobs"):

- Agent
- Deployment Group
- Server (or 'agentless')

Manual intervention goes in a Server/agentless job. You probably have a standard Agent job in your release definition. You'll need to break your release up into multiple jobs: Agent (up to the point where you need a manual intervention), Server (containing the manual intervention), then Agent again.

Comment: Is the Manual intervention is available in Azure DevOps? I'm trying to find it in Azure DevOps and not able to get it. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @Jayendran Are you using an agentless phase?

Comment: Yes, I'm tried agent less phase in Azure DevOps. I got it now. This manual intervention is only available in the release pipeline. I assumed this is also available in build pipeline(since build pipeline also contains the agentless phase)